# Variable might have not been initialised error

Tags: java, variables, model-view-controller, initialization

I am currently trying to execute a simple Java MVC Application. I have a loginbean and logindao class as model and controller. My view loginview.java has the following code.

```
package view;
import bean.loginbean;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
import dao.logindao;
public class loginview{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        loginbean l;
        System.out.println("Enter name : ");
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        String n=s.nextLine();
        int a=s.nextInt();
        l.setname(n);
        l.setage(a);
        logindao l1;
        int flag=l1.correct(l);
        if(flag==1)
            System.out.println("Correct");
        else
            System.out.println("Incorrect");
    }
}
```

I have initialized l using set methods and l1 does not have any data members. But I get the error

```
loginview.java:14: error: variable l might not have been initialized
        l.setname(n);
        ^
loginview.java:17: error: variable l1 might not have been initialized
        int flag=l1.correct(l);
```

Comment: You have declared it but it is still null.  You need `loginbean l = new loginbean();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize the variables:

```
loginbean l = new loginbean();
logindao l1 = new logindao();
```

BTW: Read about the Java naming conventions. Class names should start with an uppercase character.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a variable in method which does not have default values;

```
 loginbean l;
```

Change it to `loginbean l = new loginbean();`

Method local variables will not get default values. So you need to assign some value to them before using.

Also, for another variable,

```
logindao l1 = new logindao();
```

It is good practice to follow naming conventions when naming classes. They should use CamelCase.

So your class names should be `LoginDao` and `LoginBean`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialize the bean(loginbean) and service(logindao). You need to initialize both by calling their constructor.

Just calling setter on variable l wont initialize the loginbean.

```
LoginBean l = new LoginBean(); // Follow Camel Case letters in Java
```

Also if you declare

```
LoginBean l = null;
```

Then calling setter method on l will throw NullPointerException.